# Product of sparse polynomials with FFT

Tags: runtime-analysis, sparse-matrices, fast-fourier-transform

I need to compute the product of two polynomials $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ over a finite field. The degrees of these polynomials are $n^2$ for some integer $n$. However, we also know that the polynomials are sparse in the sense that most coefficients are zero and furthermore, only $O(n)$ of the coefficients are non-zero.

Can we compute the product $f(X)\cdot g(X)$ in runtime $O(n\cdot \log^2(n))$ via FFT? If not, could we at least do it in subquadratic runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n>0$.
Let $f(X)=X^{n^2} + X^{n(n-1)} + X^{n(n-2)}+\cdots + X^n + 1$.
Let $g(X) =X^{n^2} + X^{n-1} + X^{n-2} + \cdots + 1$.

$$\begin{aligned} 
f(X)g(X)&=f(X)X^{n^2} + f(X)(X^{n-1} + X^{n-2} + \cdots + 1)\\
&=X^{2n^2}+X^{2n^2-n} + \cdots + X^{n^2+n} + X^{n^2} + {}\\
&\quad\quad X^{n^2+n-1}+X^{n^2+n-2} +\cdots+ X^2 + X + 1\\
&=\sum_{2n\ge i\ge n+1}X^{ni} + \sum_{n^2+n-1\ge i\ge n^2+1}X^i \ \ + 2X^{n^2} + \sum_{n^2-1\ge i\ge0}X^i
\end{aligned}$$

The number of non-zero coefficients of $f(X)$ is $n+1$.
The number of non-zero coefficients of $g(X)$ is $n+1$.
The number of non-zero coefficients of $f(X)g(X)$ is $(n+1)^2-1=n^2+2n$.

It is impossible to list all nonzero coefficients of $f(X)g(X)$ in subquadratic runtime of $n$ in the worst time. So, it is impossible to compute all nonzero coefficients of $f(X)g(X)$ in subquadratic runtime of $n$.